# Two-way Repeated Measures ANOVA in Spyder-TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64

Tags: python, statistics, spyder, anova

I just started to learn to code and wanted to learn python. I am attempting to recreate an SPSS statistical analysis I already conducted on Spyder. I am doing this by replicating an example: http://www.statsmodels.org/0.6.1/examples/notebooks/generated/interactions_anova.html
My analysis is slightly smaller but quite similar. I am following the example step by step, and I am having trouble with the "Take a look at the data:" step.

My work is a 2x2 Repeated measure ANOVA. The IV is MATCH (whether the participant's preferred lighting condition was utilized or not) with two conditions. The DV is pre/post-test scores on a learning objective.

I am receiving the error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Tim\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Tim/.spyder-py3/thesis.py", line 31, in <module>
    plt.scatter(group['MATCH'], marker=symbols[j], color=colors[i-k],

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64

<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x278c15ea6d8>
```

My code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from statsmodels.compat import urlopen
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=4, suppress=True)
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option("display.width", 100)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
from statsmodels.graphics.api import interaction_plot, abline_plot
from statsmodels.stats.anova import anova_lm


data = r'C:\Users\Tim\pandas\Thesis_main.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(data)


plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
symbols = ['D', '^']
colors = ['r', 'g', 'blue']
factor_groups = data.groupby(['MATCH'])
for values, group in factor_groups:
    i,j = values
    plt.scatter(group['PRETEST'], group['POSTTEST'] marker=symbols[j], color=colors[i-1], s=144)
plt.xlabel('MATCH');
plt.ylabel('PRETEST');('POSTTEST');
```

Data:

https://github.com/tici0988/Sorting_contacts/blob/master/Thesis_main.csv

Any advice on solving this error, or pointing me in a more efficient direction would be greatly appreciated! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues with your code. The first is that you are trying to call `plt.scatter` with only an `x` argument. What are you trying to plot `group['MATCH']` against?

Next, you are trying to index your list `symbols` and/or your list `colors` by a float, which is not possible. I believe that the float you are using is the `PRETEST` and `POSTTEST` score (represented by `i` and `k` in your code). I can't see the data, but let's assume that score is a number such as `1.25`; you can't select index `1.25` in your list of 2 symbols, as that doesn't mean anything to python. Are you trying to have different symbols and colors to represent different things? If so, to represent what? If not, simply take out the `marker=symbols[j]` and `color=colors[i-k]` arguments.

FYI, In your code, `j` is not defined; you must mean either `i` or `k` when you typed `symbols[j]`

Comment: Thank you for your help @sacul Yes, you are correct that PRE/POSTTEST are floats. I am trying to plot the data at the moment as I follow an example. I have also posted a link to the data.

Comment: If you're trying to plot `group['MATCH']` against something, you need to specify what you want to plot it against. For instance, in the example, they plotted `['X']` against `['S']`

Comment: I changed my plot code to plot the match against the PRE and POST, however, I am still receiving the same error. What exactly does "marker=symbols[j]" mean?

Comment: First, `j` is not defined in your code, which is a problem. But that line is trying to say: use the `j`th symbol in your list `symbols` (which you defined above) as the marker type in your plot. For instance, if j were 1, then it would use the `^` symbol as a marker, which in `matplotlib.pyplot`, is an upward facing triangle.

Comment: Ok, the j is defined now. Do I have the variables grouped together correctly?

Comment: You've got them grouped by pre and post, it kind of depends what you want to do with it. Think about what you want on your x axis, what you want on your y axis, and how you want match to be represented in your plot

Comment: I want them grouped by Match(1) or Mismatch(2) on the y-axis, and the pre/post to be on the x-axis.